# Trailing forward slash in react-router routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am using react-router v3.0.0 with react v15.1.0. I have the following route setup:

```
ReactDom.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={BrowserHistory}>
        <Route path='shop' component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Shop} />
            <Route path='/product' component={ProductView} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

As you can see, my base `Route` for the application has a path of `'shop'`. As far as the user is concerned, this **should** result in 2 separate routes, `http://example.com/shop` and `http://example.com/shop/product`. However, this is not the case.

When I deploy the aforementioned code, `http://example.com/shop` renders correctly, but `http://example.com/shop/product` renders nothing. In fact, I get a console error:

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "/shop/product" did not match any routes
```

So, I altered my setup a bit:

```
ReactDom.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={BrowserHistory}>
        <Route path='shop/' component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Shop} />
            <Route path='product' component={ProductView} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

This will allow me to render `http://example.com/shop/` (notice the trailing forward slash), `http://example.com/shop/product`, **but NOT `http://example.com/shop`.**

Is is possible to render `http://example.com/shop`, `http://example.com/shop/`, `http://example.com/shop/product` within the same app?

Comment: `/shop/` and `/shop` mean the same thing so they are indistinguishable. However, `/shop/product` is different from those and can be distinguished.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that your first setup failed is because React Router `<Route>` `path`s that begin with a slash are considered absolute to the root (`/`), even when they are nested.

Your second setup is close, but you should not include the trailing slash in `shop/`. React Router will join the paths together for you, you do not need to worry about including a slash to join `shop` and `product`. (For example, look at [this configuration](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/c3cd9675bd8a31368f87da74ac588981cbd6eae7/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#adding-an-index) which uses relative paths)

```
ReactDom.render(<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={BrowserHistory}>
    <Route path='shop' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Shop} />
        <Route path='product' component={ProductView} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Ah, this works. Thank you very much! If you would edit your answer to include the working code, then I will happily accept the answer.

Comment: Done. React Router is a bit confusing with relative paths because `<Route>`s can use them, but `<Link>`s cannot, but it is what is is :/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the route setup like

```
ReactDom.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={BrowserHistory}>
        <Route path='shop' component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Shop} />
            <Route path='/shop/product' component={ProductView} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

You route didn't work because your `product` route was absolute with your url since it begins with a `/`. I think a better way would be to remove it and use the route as

```
<Route path='product' component={ProductView} />
```