# What's the difference between http://domain/path and http://domain/path/ in a url

Tags: html, explorer

I served a react page under `127.0.0.1/react/` sub directary with my gateway. It can be viewed by explorer with `127.0.0.1/react/`. But if I input `127.0.0.1/react` it returns my vue page served under `127.0.0.1` which failed to match any routes.
There is another example https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods.
`https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods` is okay while `https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/` returns `404 not found`. What's the difference?
Ordinary users might treat them as same url, they would expect both of them can access the page. So how should I make them both accessable?

Comment: What's your gateway? Nginx? It'll all come down to the configuration... Nginx AND ReactJS. i.e. How do you handle the trailing slash? e.g. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216330/trailing-forward-slash-in-react-router-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server can return whatever it wants for any path, and  doesn't need to follow any particular standard conventions.  However, most servers do follow some norms:

- `/react/` usually ends up fetching the index file (usually `index.html` unless configured otherwise) from the `react` folder under the web root.  This is returned to the client transparent... the client isn't redirected.
- `/react`  This is a request for a file named `react` under the main root.  However, in the absence of such file, and the presence of a folder, it's common to redirect the client to `/react/`.

How you do this depends entirely on your server configuration.  You didn't tell us the server, so we can't point you in the right direction.

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot to configure to redirect `/react` to `/react/`. configure a redirect and place it after `/react/` proxypass and it works. Also adding a same proxypass of `/react` works. It should also work for nginx.